# Constants for Error Codes

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0

When building an `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` class, it is necessary to be able to return error codes for failure states. According to the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749), these should be things like `invalid_request`, `unauthorized_client`,etc.

Currently, I have these hand-coded:

```
context.SetError("access_denied", "Invalid Username or Password");
```

Is there a built-in .Net class that provides these codes as constants within the system/Packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a built-in .Net class that provides these codes as constants within the system/Packages?

No. The `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth` package (where the OAuth2 authorization server middleware lives) has an `OAuthConstants` class that exposes the error codes you're looking for, but it's internal: https://github.com/jchannon/katanaproject/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/OAuthConstants.cs#L49-L57

That said, nothing prevents you from creating your own constants class.

Comment: Thanks. A centrally provided constants class would have been better, but I'll just roll my own.